# The connection of multiple adjectives

Tags: adjectives

In the following sentence:

> “现在大家坐上‘复兴号’，不仅更**宽敞明亮舒服**、速度更快，在车上打电话的信号也更好了，这些都是能感受到的变化。” 丁荣军说，“我们正在研究怎么接入媒体，让视频也能到车上去。”

The relevant part means:

> Not only it is more spacious, lighter, and more comfortable, and faster, but the signal of the phone is also better. All of them are the changes you can sense.

Usually, the adjectives are concatenated with a conjunction, such as 和 or 并. But in this case the adjectives are not concatenated with any conjunction, and it is in the form of "ABC", not "A、B和C".

Why does it use no conjunction, and how can I know in which situations it is required to use a conjunction to concatenate adjectives.

Also, does the meaning get different if I add 和 in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You do not always need 和 between adjectives.
You could use 宽敞明亮、舒服.
宽敞明亮 usually works together.

"现在大家坐上‘复兴号’，
Now (for) everyone sitting on the 'D train'

不仅更宽敞明亮舒服、速度更快，
it is not only bigger, brighter, more comfortable, faster,

在车上打电话的信号也更好了，
the phone signal in the train is also better,

这些都是能感受到的变化。”
these are all perceptible changes

丁荣军说，
Ding Rong Jun said

“我们正在研究怎么接入媒体，让视频也能到车上去。
We are researching how integrate media

让视频也能到车上去。
(and) also make video work on (the train).

Comment: 复兴号 -> Fuxing Train; at least the broadcast on the train call it like this.

Comment: @tsh Correct. That’s why it is enclosed by the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not the case here, but I'd like to mention that Chinese is a language that emphasizes cadence, at least to me. Sometimes putting together adjectives only serves for keeping the sentence more readable.

In your example changing the adjectives to A、B 和 C does not affect the meaning of the sentence. But if I was the person who wrote that sentence I would probably not put three two-character words together as it tends to become too long unless the phrase following it has a comparative length, like 宽敞明亮舒服，干净卫生整洁. Or I'd say 宽敞明亮舒服，运行速度更快 to match the cadence here.

As a native speaker rather than a linguist I don't think it's a issue about grammatical correctness.

Answer (score -1):

> ... 不仅更宽敞明亮舒服、速度更快，...

I take this as a punctuation issue. I would punctuate it like:

> ... 不仅更宽敞 **、** 明亮 **、** 舒服 **,** 速度更快，...

Better add the conjunction 而且 between the two clauses, like:

> ... 不仅更宽敞、（更）明亮、（更）舒服, **而且**速度更快，...

Comment: So why is it written as such and what is the difference? That is my question.

Comment: @Blaszard I already answer you *I take this as a punctuation issue.* You should read the answer closely.